# Change the color of a Button & Fade Effect with Zurb Foundation

Tags: button, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation and my question is pretty straight forward, how do I change the color of a button, like this one,`<a href="#" class="button [radius round]">Text</a>`

Now, I know there is a way to change the background color by doing this,`<a href="#" class="button [radius round]" style="background-color: #3871be">Button Text</a>`, but when I do this, I loose the fade effect to a darker color when I hover over the button, how do I get the darker color fade effect back?

[image: Side by side Zurb buttons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, going to answer my own question here, put this in my css

```
.button.custom {
    background-color: #88643d;
}
.button.custom:hover,
.button.custom:focus {
    background-color: #6d5031;
}
```

That did the trick:)